# .Net MVC: Как с откорректировать поля <Form> в post запросе, на Другую модель данных?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post, asp.net-core-mvc

**Как можно отправить форму в POST запросе, на другую модель данных (не та котарая во view)?**

У меня есть UserModel и FilterRequest модели. Чтобы отфильтровать данные мне нужно послать Post запрос на IndexFilter с FilterRequest моделью фильтраций?

*Помогите Пожалуйста как мне это сделать?*

View/User/Index.cshtml

```
@model UserModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("IndexFilter", "User", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="hidden" name ="pageNumber" value="@Model.PaginationModel.PageNumber"/>

    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col">
            <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FilterData.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <label class="control-label">Last Name</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FilterData.LastName, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Filter" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
}
```

UserController.cs

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult IndexFilter([FromBody] FilterRequest request)
{

}
```

UserModel.cs

```
public class UserModel
{
    public IList<User> Users{ get; set; }
    
    public PaginationModel PaginationModel { get; set; }

    public FilterData FilterData { get; set; }
}
```

FilterRequest.cs

```
public class FilterRequest
{
    public int PageNumber { get; set; } = 1;

    public FilterData FilterData { get; set; }
}
```

На сервер уходит Post запрос, с Form Data `pageNumber=1&FilterData.FirstName=&FilterData.LastName=Nikita&__RequestVerificationToken=Token`
Сервер ответил 415.

Comment: FromBody - это когда приходит JSON или там XML. А у вас приходит форма, т.е. FromForm

Answer (score -1):

Можно создать модель данных соответствующую приходящему в котроллер запросу, а потом смапить её в методе контроллера на ту модель которая вам нужна.

Чтобы убедиться, что на стороне клиента формируется подходящий запрос, можно воспользоваться инструментами для разработчика встроенными в браузер. Например в Chrome это вкладка Network инструмента DevTools, там можно поставить галочку Preserve log, сделать запрос и выбрать его в списке, а затем сравнить содержимое и структуру запроса с моделью на стороне сервера.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я не понимаю... Я в form посылаю ровно такие же поля, какие и принимает Controller, за исключением User... Я как понял [FromBody] не принимает поля по отдельности и не собирает нужную модель из них ....

Comment: Пожалуйста дополните ответ так, чтобы у автора вопроса не возникало дополнительных вопросов. Добавьте пример кода в ответ.

Comment: Посмотрите как выглядит ваш запрос, который формируется на стороне клиента и сравните с вашей моделью. Для этого, в браузере, если вы используете Chrome, нужно зайти в консоль разработчика, выбрать вкладку Network, поставить галочку Preverse log, сделать запрос и смотреть результат. В других браузерах тоже есть аналогичные инструменты.

Comment: Спасибо, Геннадий. Я не знал про Preverse log

Comment: Я так и думал в Form Data лежит, не объект а просто поля pageNumber=1&FilterData.FirstName=&FilterData.LastName=Nikita&__RequestVerificationToken=Token